# Directory permissions "r-s", chmod 655 does not change to "r-x", why?

Tags: directory, chmod, setuid

I created a directory in my home directory. and I set its permission as follows:

```
uhmwk.1.4$ chmod 655 dog
uhmwk.1.4$ ls -l
total 4
drw-r-sr-x 2 s9 s9 4096 Feb 14 21:57 dog
```

why is the group permission "r-s" when I set it to read and execute and it should be "r-x"?

Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that directory **setgid** is set and the execute bit is set too. This basically means that files created by other users in this directory will have the group of the directory owner.

Man page says that...

> chmod **preserves** a directory's set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits unless you explicitly specify otherwise. You can set or clear the bits with symbolic modes like u+s and g-s, and you can set (but not clear) the bits with a numeric mode.

So... If these directory mode bits have been set in the past they will remain there until you **explicitily** remove them.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer:

```
    chmod g-s <file or directory name>
```

Comment: And the long answer is? Oneline answer do not count as good one.

Comment: In this case the short answer was awesome - for me! Some people want a short answer as a reminder. The more detailed answer did not give an example, it was implied, and assumes knowledge, short answer gets the job done.